# In R I am unable to assign column names to a data frame

Tags: r

The function below goes through several CSV files and returns a data frame with file names and the number of complete rows (no missing values) in each file. Although I assign column names to complete_rows in the beginning (id and nobs), the data frame that gets returned doesn't have the same names. Why does this happen?

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    #navigate to directory
    setwd(directory)

    #keep track of row name and number of completed rows
    complete_rows <- data.frame(id=numeric(0), nobs=numeric(0))  

    #csv names
    myfiles <- list.files(pattern = "csv")

    #loop through files
    for(i in id) {

        #read each file
        current_dataset <- read.csv(myfiles[i])

        #include only files with complete datasets
        good_rows <- current_dataset[complete.cases(current_dataset),]

        #push id and number of good rows to data frame
        complete_rows <- rbind(complete_rows, c(i, nrow(good_rows)))

        #increment loop
        i <- i + 1
    }
    #return data frame
    complete_rows
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rbind` on two data.frames with identical names:

```
complete_rows <- rbind(complete_rows, data.frame(id=i, nobs=nrow(good_rows)))
```

Your code is not very idiomatic to `R` as beginneR has covered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why exactly you are experiencing that behavior, but I would propose some adjustments to your code as follows:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

#navigate to directory
setwd(directory)

#keep track of row name and number of completed rows
complete_rows <- data.frame(id=numeric(length(id)), nobs=numeric(length(id)))  

#csv names
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = "csv")

#loop through files
for(i in id) {

  #read each file
  current_dataset <- read.csv(myfiles[i])

  # write id
  complete_rows$id[i] <- i

  # write nobs
  complete_rows$nobs[i] <- sum(complete.cases(current_dataset))

  }

#return data frame
return(complete_rows)
}
```

If you only want the id and number of observations, you don't need to use `rbind` and to return something from a function you either use `return` or nothing (which would then return the last evaluated expression as far as I know). And you can initalize `complete_rows` with the number of rows you need, since you already know that in advance. You also don't need to manually increment `i` in your for loop, since that is done already in `for(i in id)`.

Does this work for you?

Edit/note:

It would probably be even better to read all files at once into a list and then operate on them.